# SQL- how to get users under warranty in past 90 days

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with custid,purchase_timestamp (dd-mm-yyyy) and warranty_period in days.
I need the count of customers who either made purchase in  last 90 days + users who made purchase before 90 days but their warranty period falls between these last 90 days. 
How can i write SQL for this. Thanks

```
|**custid |    warranty_period  |   purchase_timestamp
|1        |      365            |   03-01-2017  
|2        |      30             |   03-04-2017
|3        |     10              |   25-05-2017
|4        |      30             |   20-05-2017
|5        |     365             |   04-06-2017
|6        |     100             |   18-06-2017
|7        |     90              |   30-06-2017
|8        |     10              |   05-07-2017
|9        |        30           |   09-07-2017
|10       |     365             |   17-07-2017**



SELECT COUNT(custid)
    FROM db
    HAVING SUM(warranty_period+purchase_timestamp)> getdate()-90 or purchase_timestamp>getdate()-90
```

This is my trial query, and it just does not move

Comment: mysql or sql-server?

Comment: What query did you write for this? What issue you are facing with that query? You need to show what you have done. Don't expect a ready made answer from SO. This is not a code writing service.

Comment: I am using mysql

Comment: What is data-type of `purchase_timestamp`? Is it VARCHAR ?

Comment: its timestamp date and time format

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: @PreetiKumar: At least spare some time to see the answers too and reply to them.

Comment: The answers above didnt help, i have a new version of query i arrived at with trial and error method. But that also throws error. I shall post it

Answer (score 0):

If i understand you correctly you need something like this:

```
select count(custid)
  from db
  where datediff(day, purchase_timestamp, getdate()) <= 90 or warranty_period < 90
```

`datediff()` gives you the difference between two dates. The first argument `day`, specifies that you want the difference in days.

Comment: Yes, I did try it and it works in sql server but I see now he added the mysql tag so my answer is useless for him.